# Java: Select the first file in a directory

Tags: java, file, select, directory

I'm asking for a Java code.

I'm looking for a way to select the first file in a directory in order to process it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please dont ask for code. Ask the problems you run, into WHEN YOU WRITE YOUR OWN code.

Comment: `I'm asking for a Java code.` Sorry But You should not do that on **SOF** without showing your efforts to achieve target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a DirectoryStream. Documentation can be found at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bu is there another solution? This one uses java.nio and I can code only with Java 7.

Comment: If you won't already know what the name of the file is, then unfortunately I don't believe there is another way.

Comment: Actually, the objective is to find the name of the first file in the directory in order to rename it...